# How to send string without double quotes in spring rest api response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-rest

I have two projects, projectA (spring boot), projectB (spring)

In these two projects I have similar API that returns a string. But the response from the projectB API have double quotes and projectA doesnt have double quotes in the response

**ProjectA** [This is spring boot project]

```
@PostMapping(path = "/tenants/{tenantId}/script/getNormalString")
    public String getNormalString(@PathVariable("tenantId") String tenantId,HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        try {
            String uuid = "normalString";
            return uuid;
        }  catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error in getNormalString-> {}",e.getMessage(),e);
            throw new RestApiException(FAILED_GET,e.getMessage(),e);
        } 
    }
```

**Response**

```
normalString
```

**ProjectB**

```
@PostMapping(path = "/tenants/{tenantId}/script/getNormalString")
    public String getNormalString(@PathVariable("tenantId") String tenantId,HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        try {
            String uuid = "normalString";
            return uuid;
        }  catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error in getNormalString-> {}",e.getMessage(),e);
            throw new RestApiException(FAILED_GET,e.getMessage(),e);
        } 
    }
```

**Response**

```
"normalString"
```

Can someone help me out why there is difference in the response.? Is there way to send the response without double quotes.?
I tried using *@Produces("text/plain")* but still there is no change in response

Comment: What happens if you add ResponseBody to return type in ProjectB endpoint ?
public @ResponseBody String getNormalString(.....)

Comment: @S B ,I mentioned *@RestController* on top of the class. So I don't need to add *@ResponseBody*

Comment: What is the `Accept` header of the request and the `Content-Type` of the response ? For whatever the content type is, are both projects using the same library and configuration to convert the string into that content type?